# Memory issue using DAX query in python script

Tags: python-3.x, dax, azure-data-lake, ssas-tabular

I am having memory issue when I execute DAX query inside the code in ref picture. If its like 10000 row it works however more than that it create memory issue. My query may return up to 50 Millions of data.
Question 1: What should be the efficient way to execute the query.
Question 2: What settings or properties might change to adjust huge amount of data.
Question 3: Is that possible to use partition and split data to fill into data table?

I am new in python coding. Please suggest me if code needs to change or any other efficient way to pull the data and send to data frame? my end goal is to send all data to CSV format into data lake. Its currently working however, for smaller amount of rows. I have tested till 10k is working in few min. its super inefficient seems to me.

Thanks in Advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how I would automate it, but the **Export Data** function from DAX Studio works really fast. I just did 500k rows in under a minute. It works against tables in the model, so if you are working with a DAX Expression, you would have to create it as a DAX Table in the model first.

[image: Exporting to csv from DAX Studio]